# How do I acess first and last letter in the dataframe´s column cells?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df["first_letter"] = df["ITEM"][0]
df["last_letter"] = df["ITEM"][1]
```

or

```
for cell in df["ITEM"]:
  df["first_letter"] = cell[0]
  df["last_letter"] = cell[1]
```

do not work.
As a result I want two new columns: one with the first and another with the last letter of the  existing column df["ITEM"].

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.str[0]` and `.str[-1]` respectively:

```py
df["first_letter"] = df["ITEM"].str[0]
df["last_letter"] = df["ITEM"].str[-1]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    ITEM first_letter last_letter
0  Hello            H           o
1  World            W           d
```